# Using Docker to replicate a flask app set up?

Tags: azure, docker

I have not used Docker before at all, but I have a flask app running on an Azure server right now which I would like the mostly replicate to another server.

- Ubuntu 16.10
- Anaconda for my Python environments
- A few systemd files to configure nginx and uwsgi

My goal is to start fresh without having to do a fresh install of the OS (I do not have the ability to do this) on my current server. I have a few issues with environments and multiple Python versions which I would like to escape from.

I would then like to take this set up and send it over to another server which is completely fresh (a brand new Azure instance which hasn't been touched yet). Is this possible with Docker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make things clear, Docker is not a technolgy to migrate applications from one server to another. Docker is a "vitualization" technology which allows you to isolate applications when they are running. Once you have this isolation, the Docker containers can be migrated to any server having just Docker installed. Thus you releive yourself from issues like "It works on this machine, but it doesn't work on that".

In order to do that, you need first to Dockerize your application. Your requirements are very common, and there are many samples online of how to containarize such applications.

However, you need first to learn about Docker to get started (which need a couple of hours/days). You can start learning about Docker [here](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/). Once you have your application dockerized and working on one machine, moving it to another server is a piece of cake.

Comment: Thanks. Is it something which can be done on an existing machine? As I hinted at, I face a few issues on this particular machine because when I set it up, I installed multiple versions of Python and venvs (Python 3.6) and then Anaconda (which I currently use). I want to dockerize my set up on this machine, but I want it to be a 'fresh start' if possible.

Comment: @trench yes you can use the same machine. Take a look at the supported OS to install docker. https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/